# Application Installer with Tomcat

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, installation

I have a simple Java web application using HSQLDB embedded database. The application is packaged as a simple war file.  part of the requirement is to develop an application installer, that will:

1. Installs TOMCAT
2. resolves port conflicts (if any)
3. Deploys the war
4. Creates a shortcut that starts the service and launch the browser

I will also need to do this for both MAC and Windows, Any Ideas on how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks very simple to me. Solution:

1. Do not rely on the target system having/not having JRE. Have a compatible JRE packaged with your application installer and forcefully install it (I've had compatibility issues).
2. In the installer, you should have the installer for the database application (if required), the JRE folder and the tomcat folder with the war file already in place. Just zip/tar these things together and unzip/untar them during  installation.
3. Set the `CATALINA_HOME` variable to your tomcat folder as a system variable.
4. Set the `JRE_HOME` and append `PATH` with your `JRE` folder and `JRE/bin` folder 
   respectively in the same session in which you start tomcat. This forces tomcat 
   to pick your JRE version and does not disturb any other application running on 
   the JVM.

Comment: how do i make sure that the default tomcat port 8080 is not already being used on the client's machine? is there any way of automating this reather than asking the client what port number they wish to use as some clients are not technical at all.

Comment: @Maro You can try to connect to port 8080 or vice versa to listen on the port. In the former case, if connection fails, the port is free; if connection is successful, another application uses it. In the latter case, you'll get _"Address already in use"_ error, which means the port is used by something else; otherwise it's free. Anyway providing a way for users to customize the port looks a good option.

Comment: I really don't see the answer to this question. The answer tells you the what not the how...